# When using transfer checked, I am getting Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x1 when.. The wallets are funded

Tags: web3.js

I am able to create associated token accounts, but when I try to transfer I keep getting this error. I am paying with another wallet, but it works extremely randomally.

```
const fromUserKeypair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(sk);
  const connection = new Connection(quickNodeUrl);
  const payerKeypair = getPrimitivesSolanaAccount();
  const tokenAddressPublicKey = new PublicKey(tokenAddress);
  const toWalletPublicKey = new PublicKey(toWallet);

  const fromTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
    connection,
    payerKeypair,
    tokenAddressPublicKey,
    fromUserKeypair.publicKey
  ).catch((err) => {
    console.log('token account error', err);
  });

  const tokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
    connection,
    payerKeypair,
    tokenAddressPublicKey,
    toWalletPublicKey
  ).catch((err) => {
    console.log('token account error', err);
  });

  if (tokenAccount && fromTokenAccount) {
    console.log('ABOUT TO SEND');
    const signature = await transferChecked(
      connection,
      payerKeypair,
      fromTokenAccount.address,
      tokenAddressPublicKey,
      tokenAccount.address,
      fromUserKeypair,
      1,
      0
    ).catch((err) => {
      console.log('transfer error', err);
    });
    return signature;
  }
```

Comment: please update the question with the full transaction log output

Answer (score 1):

This error could occur if the `fromTokenAccount` doesn't have a sufficient token balance to transfer